# Text alignment in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, formatting

I am developing a crystal report and data is also coming fine but I am unable to format the fields in the same, just like a **comment** field must be **multiline** but when I select the "can Grow" in Format object section, the display is vague.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can Grow with a value zero stands for the display will grow to multiple lines till it is displayed fully.

As the grow can happen multiple lines, you can adjust the width of the item so that it will not overlap with other item.

What should You do:

1. Set can grow property to zero
2. Resize the item (for which you set cangrow 0) so that it will not overlap the item of the next column.

Comment: I cannot extend the comment field as page width is restricted, I mean I am not able to extend the width of the Report.

Comment: Right click the filed below your comments heading. Set the Can grow property to 0. Make sure the width of filed not overlapping with the field next to it.